# GUI's I display aren't consistent sizes

Tags: java, user-interface, scaling

I've been designing a program that acts as a graphing calculator and noticed that it was being scaled to a larger size (possibly by Windows).  I recently reinstalled Eclipse and the JDK/JRE and now things are being outputted at the intended size. [Screenshot of the 2 GUI's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7LCm.png)

I didn't change any of my code, the larger GUI's are run from an executable JAR I made before reinstalling stuff and the smaller ones are run straight from the code after.

Is there any way to control this in the code I write?

Comment: Is this a `JavaFX`, `AWT`, or `Swing` question?

Comment: It is entirely possible that later versions of Java had better rendering of font sizes.  A 12 point font literally means each line of text is ¹²⁄₇₂ of an inch high, not 12 pixels high, so a correct renderer should be taking the video mode and the monitor’s dimensions into account.